# Jquery Show Hide & Close

Tags: jquery

Friends i need Jquery help below is my requirement.

First Step -> Anchor Rollover Show Div

Second Step -> Same Anchor Link Click Show Another Div and hide before div which we are showing on rollover & also contain these links. On this Div we have close link if we click on it, it returns to the main one i.e. Rollover Links show div.

Comment: Please post what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can find your answer here with various jQuery animations

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Check it out - its simple and easy